# Locate imported aar files

Tags: flutter, native, aar

My latest project requires me to integrate an aar file with my Flutter App. I have successfuly created the dependancy by importing the project from my local maven repository. How can i access the imported files? I cant seem to find them anywhere in my projects directory.